# WPF Prism 6.2 (Unity) - How to register event, when a module load is initiated

Tags: wpf, prism

I want to show a message in a SplashScreen, which module is in loading...
But with Prism-ModuleManager it is only possible to register an event for "LoadModuleCompleted".

Was trying to use the Prism-Sources to implement an event handler for "LoadModuleInitiated" by my own, but with no luck ...
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/Prism.v6.2.0/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Modularity/ModuleManager.cs

Any idea, how it could be possible to get an event, when the load starts?!

Is there a way to add an own event handler for this, without dealing with the full prism source packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by creating a ModuleInitializer class that implements the IModuleInitializer interface.  If in the bootstrappers ConfigureContainer method you get a handle to Prism’s ModuleInitializer and register it as a named instance, you can get a handle to it in your custom ModuleInitializer and use it for the heavy lifting.  Doing this, you can inject yourself into the module loading process.  I have seen this pattern of getting a handle to some interface and then using it via containment to do something custom in a number of places, so I am by no means the original author of this approach. Not sure that describes it that well.  Hopefully the following code will help get the point across.

**Custom ModuleInitializer**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Prism.Modularity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace GD.Common.Prism
{
   /// <summary>
   /// This class implements a custom Prism module initializer.  Having this allows us to monitor 
   /// the module loading/initialization progress so we can display applications startup progress, 
   /// and publish out an event letting the application and the associated modules when 
   /// initialization is complete.
   /// </summary>
   public class ModuleInitializer : IModuleInitializer
   {
      private readonly IUnityContainer mUnityContainer = null;
      private readonly IModuleInitializer mDefaultModuleUnitializer = null;
      private readonly IModuleCatalog mModuleCatalog = null;
      private List<ModuleInfo> mLoadedModules = new List<ModuleInfo>();

      /// <summary>
      /// Parameterized Constructor.  Parameters supplied by dependency injection.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="aUnityContainer">untity DI container</param>
      /// <param name="aModuleCatalog">the current module catalog</param>
      public ModuleInitializer(IUnityContainer aUnityContainer, IModuleCatalog aModuleCatalog)
      {
         mUnityContainer = aUnityContainer;
         mModuleCatalog = aModuleCatalog;

         // Retrieve the default module initializer.  We will utilize this implementation to perform
         // the actual loading.  We just want to be the middle man for status
         mDefaultModuleUnitializer = mUnityContainer.Resolve<IModuleInitializer>("defaultModuleInitializer");
      }

      public void Initialize(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
      {
         // Custom Code HERE

         mDefaultModuleUnitializer.Initialize(moduleInfo);

         mLoadedModules.Add(moduleInfo);



      }
   }
}
```

**Bootstrapper Updates**

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
   base.ConfigureContainer();

   // Get the provided module initializer
   var defaultModuleInitializer = Container.Resolve<IModuleInitializer>();
   // Save it off so that our custom initializer can use it to do the heavy lifting
   Container.RegisterInstance<IModuleInitializer>("defaultModuleInitializer", defaultModuleInitializer);
   // register our implementation as the default
   Container.RegisterType<IModuleInitializer, GD.Common.Prism.ModuleInitializer>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```

I hope this helps with an approach to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!